# Using tcolorbox with listings on gives entry in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox` for a documentation. Here is my code?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8,documentation}

\newcommand{\lcmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash{#1}}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%%
\section{The Problem}
\subsection{Example 1: listing on}
%%
\begin{tcblisting}{title= Example 1}
    \section{Main Section} 
    An Example you to usethe section commands.
    \subsection{Sub Section} 
    \subsubsection{SubSub Section} 
\end{tcblisting}
%
\end{document}
```

The compilation adds the section of the snippet to the TOC.

[image: The output]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED** after follow-up: adding other packages.

Change the `tocdepth` before the `tcblisting` --to suppress the entries to the ToC--  and restore it afterwards.

Use `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}` and
`\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}`

The section within the `tcblisting` will start with #1.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}% added to check compatiblity
\usepackage{todonotes}% idem

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,documentation}
\newcommand{\lcmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash{#1}}} 

\newcounter{oldsection}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Introduction}
    \section{The Problem}
    \subsection{Example 1: listing on}

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} % suppress all entries to ToC<<<
    \setcounter{oldsection}{\thesection} % save section number
    \addtocounter{section}{-\thesection} % start numbering with 1

    \begin{tcblisting}{title= Example 1}
        \section{Main Section} 
        An Example you to use the section commands.
        \subsection{Sub Section} 
        \subsubsection{SubSub Section} 
        \section{Conclusions}
        \subsection{Another Sub Section} 
    \end{tcblisting}

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}} % restore <<<<
    \setcounter{section}{\theoldsection} % % restore <<<<...    

    \section{Another Section}  
    \subsection{Last subsection}    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this should be made by a dedicated environment.

Comment: @SimonDispa The solution is working, but in the case I add (e.g.) `\usepackage{mathtools}`, then it is no longer working. I get as error message   <br/>


`./mwe-listings.tex:17: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.17 ...tocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
                                                   % suppress all entries to...`. <br/>

The same happens with `\usepackage{todonotes}`.

Comment: @Ulrich It is solved. See the updated answer.

Comment: @SimonDispa, :-)